# Can I avoid blind vias in this PCI-E gold finger fanout?

Tags: pcb, layout, pcie

I'm planning a PCB project with PCI-E connector. After looking at some docs about PCI-E, I found one problem regarding the fanout the PCI-E gold fingers, the X16 pinout defines as below (part of whole 164 pins):

[image: Schematic]

You see, the opposite side of two GND pins are one data pair. So, If I want to connect the GND pins to the ground plane, I maybe cannot avoid using blind vias. So, I wonder if blind vias are necessary for such a situation? Are there any routing methods or suggestions to avoid using blind vias?

Comment: `Are there any routing method or suggestions to avoid using of blind vias?` Yeah, create a layout and gerber for your PCB and show what layers have what vias.You can put your ground pins of your PCIe connector on a separate layer specifically for ground.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never had to do this on any PCIe, Mini PCIe or M.2 card I've ever built.

Bring short, wide traces from the GND fingers to the interior of the board, and drop the vias to the GND plane there. There's still ample room to get the signal pairs past these vias.

Below is an example. Note that the vias are shared with GND pins top and bottom.

[image]